# OpenCV image array, 4D matrix

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix

I am trying to store a `IPL_DEPTH_8U`, 3 channel image into an array so that I can store 100 images in memory.

To initialise my 4D array I used the following code (rows,cols,channel,stored):

```
int size[] = { 324, 576, 3, 100 };
CvMatND* cvImageBucket; = cvCreateMatND(3, size, CV_8U);
```

I then created a matrix and converted the image into the matrix

```
CvMat *matImage = cvCreateMat(Image->height,Image->width,CV_8UC3 );
cvConvert(Image, matImage );
```

How would I / access the CvMatND to copy the CvMat into it at the position of stored?

e.g. `cvImageBucket(:,:,:,0) = matImage; // copied first image into array`

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493687/accessing-elements-of-cvcreatematnd/6525748#6525748

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this as both C and C++. If you want to work in C++, you could use the (in my opinion) simpler [cv::Mat structure](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) to store each of the images, and then use these to populate a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) with all the images.

For example:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> imageVector;
cv::Mat newImage;

newImage = getImage();       // where getImage() returns the next image,
                             // or an empty cv::Mat() if there are no more images
while (!newImage.empty())
{
    // Add image to vector
    imageVector.push_back(image);

    // get next image
    newImage = getImage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing something similar to:

for ith matImage

```
memcpy((char*)cvImageBucket->data+i*size[0]*size[1]*size[2],(char*)matImage->data,size[0]*size[1]*size[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with `@Chris` that it is best to use `vector<Mat>` rather than a `4D matrix`, this answer is just to be a reference for those who really need to use `4D` matrices in OpenCV (even though it is a very unsupported, undocumented and unexplored thing with so little available online and claimed to be working just fine!).

So, suppose you filled a `vector<Mat> vec` with `2D` or `3D` data which can be `CV_8U`, `CV_32F` etc.

One way to create a 4D matrix is

```
vector<int> dims = {(int)vec.size(), vec[0].rows, vec[0].cols};
Mat m(dims, vec[0].type(), &vec[0]);
```

However, this method fails when the vector is not continuous which is typically the case for big matrices. If you do this for a discontinuous matrix, you will get a `segmentation fault` or `bad access error` when you would like to use the matrix (i.e. copying, cloning, etc). To overcome this issue, you can copy matrices of the vector one by one into the 4D matrix as follows:

```
Mat m2(dims, vec[0].type());
for (auto i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
    vec[i].copyTo(temp.at<Mat>(i));
}
```

Notice that both methods require the matrices to be the same resolution. Otherwise, you may get undesired results or errors.

Also, notice that you can always use `for loops` but it is generally not a good idea to use them when you can `vectorize`.