# C++ equivalent of numpy.expand_dims() and numpy.concatenate()

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

As it mentioned in the title, I currently have some 2D images data read from OpenCV, I need to change the dimension to 4D. E.g., dimension `[320, 720]` to `[1, 320, 720, 1]`, and then make the entire data a single 4D matrix.

In Python, I can just do `numpy.expand_dims()` for each of those images and then `numpy.concatenate()` them together. I'm wondering if there is some equivalent APIs that I could use in C++. I've found `expand_dims()` in `Tensorflow`, but it only works on tensors, and I haven't found anything for `concatenate()` yet.

Libraries like `OpenCV`, `Tensorflow`, `Boost` are welcomed. But I want to keep things lighter, so it would be better if I can implement by myself (if not too complicated). Thank you in advance.

Comment: `expand_dims` just uses `reshape`; look at its Python code.  So if the array package is built like `numpy` around a flat databuffer plus shape and strides attributes. it's an easy task.  `concatenate` is compiled, but I think it allocates a target array, and copies the inputs to appropriate slots.  So it's building on basic numpy building blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expand_dims` plus `concatenate`, could in a more iterative language be written as:

```
In [107]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [109]: y = np.zeros((2,3,4,3),dtype=int)
In [110]: for i in range(2):
     ...:     for j in range(3):
     ...:         y[i,:,:,j] = x
     ...:         
In [111]: y
Out[111]: 
array([[[[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 1,  1,  1],
         [ 2,  2,  2],
         [ 3,  3,  3]],

        [[ 4,  4,  4],
         [ 5,  5,  5],
        ....
         [10, 10, 10],
         [11, 11, 11]]]])
```

In other words, all you need is the ability to create a target array of the right size, and the ability to copy the 2d arrays into appropriate slots.

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration. But I assume I could not do it dynamically in an easy way in C++?

Comment: What do you know about the `OpenCV` interface with `c++`?  If your source arrays/images come from that, then the starting point for expanding them is knowing their structures - the classes and methods.

Comment: A search on `opencv 4d` turns up a lot of links, including some SO, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386278/opencv-image-array-4d-matrix